# Unobtrusive Validation on dynamic form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am calling an MVC controller which returns a razor view that has jQuery Validation and unobtrusive validation enabled.  Here is the code that fetches the view:

Target is the target div that the html will go into.  When target.html(result) is called, I get an error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined jquery.validate.js:346

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: url,
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).success(function (result) {
            var form = $(document).find("form");
            target.html(result);                               
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#" + form.attr("id"));
        }).fail(function(result) {
           //
        });
```

I've tried to reparse with  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#" + form.attr("id"));, but the error happens before that line can run.

Any suggestions?  Is there a way to temporarily disable unobtrusive validation?

Comment: what is target basically?